# Why is the tensor product of two vector spaces a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

We defined the tensor product of $v$ and $w$ to just mean a "symbol" $e_{vw}$, then considered the subspace spanned by all these symbols, and finally we quotient out by relations to make the tensor product between two vectors bilinear. The resulting vector space is the tensor product of $V$ and $W$.

I don't understand why this is a vector space.. sure, we've said it's the span of a bunch of symbols, but what does it even mean to "add" together two symbols? How is equality defined in our vector space?

Comment: You can "generate" the smallest vector space containing your "symbols" $e_{vw}$, no problem. It will be the linear span, as you said. A linear span is a vector space by definition.

Comment: If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, and $W$ is $m$-dimensional, then the tensor product is $nm$-dimensional. So as a vector space, $V \otimes W$ is just $\Bbb{R}^{nm}$. The "symbols" $e_{vw}$ just correspond to the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{nm}$, after choosing some ordering of the bases of $V$ and $W$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but my question is why is the linear span "well-defined"? For example, suppose we consider the span {$(1,0)$,$ (1,1,1)$}? It doesn't make sense since we have no method of adding $(1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$, which is the point of confusion for me

Comment: We do not add $e_v=(1,0)$ and $e_w=(1,1,1)$, but we add elements of type $e_{vw}=e_v\otimes e_w$. The basis for $V\otimes W$ consists of vectors $e_{vw}$ and not of $e_v$, $e_w$, which are basis vectors of $V$ and $W$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If $v_1,\cdots v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,\ldots w_m$ is a basis of $W$, then 
$$
\{v_i\otimes w_j\mid 1\le i\le n,1\le j\le m\}
$$
is a basis of $V\otimes W$. So we write $e_{vw}=e_v\otimes e_w$.